# openlayers 3 multipolygon query

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have this multi polygon

MULTIPOLYGON (((179.9999 89.9999, 179.9999 67, 150 69, 90 8, 70 -60, -20 -60, -40 36, -25 66, -14 72, 0 89.9999, 179.9999 89.9999)), ((-170 89.9999, -170 66, -179.9999 67, -179.9999 89.9999, -170 89.9999)))

it extends all the way up north past the bounds of the map, I'm very new to this and I cant for the life of me figure out why it goes past the top of the map

I'm using a standard openlayers map with and I get the polygons from my database, then I read them in using javascript

```
var items = JSON.parse(resulta);

for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    var format = new ol.format.WKT();

    if (items[i].WKT.length > 0) {
        for (y = 0; y < items[i].WKT.length; y++) {
            var feature = format.readFeature(items[i].WKT[y], {
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
            if (items[i].type === 1) {
                vectorSourcetype1.addFeature(feature);
            }
            else if (items[i].type === 2) {
                vectorSourcetype2.addFeature(feature);
            }
            else if (items[i].type === 3) {
                vectorSourcetype3.addFeature(feature);
            }
        }
    }                    
}
```

I have a jsfiddle link here where you can see the polygon, how do I stop the polygon going over the tope of the map?

http://jsfiddle.net/7vhd23nd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your code, but with the projection.

You are using the spherical mercator projection, but some of your points are outside the bounds of the projections.
(you can find the projection bounds here http://epsg.io/3857 )

This is the reason for those stretched polygons.

You could cut your geometries (if possible), or you could use another projection, otherwise you need a spherical representation (like google earth)